# How to change the command for comment toggling

Tags: spacemacs, evil, commands, comment

`spacemacs` with `Evil` uses <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to toggle whether a line is commented or not.

I'd like to change it to <kbd>,</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. How should I go about this in my `.spacemacs` file?

Comment: Do you mean `g c` (the extra c in `g c c` doesn't seem to do anything special for me except start a new command)?  Your preferred binding is a bit contrary to spacemacs' way of working because `,` is already used to access commands for the current major mode.  Does it have to be that key combination?  If so, I think you might need to define a tiny minor mode that just defines that key, because that key combination might be bound in many modes' keymaps?

Comment: Nevermind, I never managed to adapt to `spacemacs` and reverted to `vim`. I'll happily mark an answer as accepted if it is put forward, but my personal preferences on the topic no longer matter too much.